# Yarn/NPM script making a git pull request fails

Tags: json, git, ubuntu, npm, yarnpkg

I'm working on a WP project on my local machine with Vagrant virtualization.

I created a script in my package.json so i can easily merge my branches, push to Gitlab and pull the git repo on my staging environment via NPM or Yarn

I added my staging server's public key to the deployment keys in my gitlab project, tested it and it works.

my package.json content:

```
{
  "name": "axis",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A development environment based on Vagrant, optimized for WP development",
   "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "latest",
    "node-sass": "latest",
    "watch": "latest",
    "onchange": "latest",
    "postcss-cli": "latest"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build":      "node-sass www/wp-content/themes/axis/sass/screen.scss www/wp-content/themes/axis/stylesheets/screen.css && yarn run autopre",
    "autopre":    "postcss --use autoprefixer www/wp-content/themes/axis/stylesheets/*.css -d www/wp-content/themes/axis/stylesheets/",
    "watch":      "yarn run watch:css",
    "watch:css" : "onchange 'www/wp-content/themes/axis/sass/**/*' -- yarn run build",
    "gitmerge": "git checkout staging && git merge dev && git checkout dev && git push --all origin && ssh ***@***.nl \" cd www/axis.nl && echo 'it works till here' && git pull origin staging;\""
  }
}
```

When I run the script i get the following error:

`Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

And here follows the weird part:
When I repeat the command step by step I don't get the error and it successfully pulls the repo.

If I Google the error I get thousands of hits but not for this specific situation.

anyone with a similar situation?

Comment: Which user on the server is actually invoking `npm`?

Comment: @NehalJWani Thanks for thinking with me! I SSH in to my server with my own username. The NPM script is on my local machine and connecting to the server using this username as well, authentication via my public key.

Comment: How are you running the script? Do you prepend it with `sudo` ?